# How to do excel file name should be datetime stamp on download?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to download the excel file to import data, the file name will be timestamp, how can I use this on download? this is my code, thanks in advance.

```
    $filename = "ersvp".date("Y-m-d").".csv";
    $csv_file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
```

Comment: what cake version are you really using? you cannot tag it with 1.3 and 2.x!

Comment: This also has nothing to do with mysql!

Comment: Also, what you are doing is not the cake2.x way.. take a look at the response object and its documentation. that's how you are supposed to do it (never send headers manually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`time()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) produces the current timestamp:

```
$filename = "ersvp".time().".csv";
```

**edit**

For a format like `Y-m-d H:i:s` use:

```
$filename = urlencode("ersvp".date("Y-m-d H:i:s").".csv");
```

Make sure you [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) since you will have spaces in your file name.

Comment: by the way  my mean is to datetime stamp, not time stamp.

Comment: by using current datetime stamp

Comment: i want like that ersvp2013-02-25-6:13:35

Comment: how can i produce datetime stamp?

Comment: well John u tried a lot, thanks very mych i can use it $filename = "ersvp".date('Y-m-d H:i:s').".csv"; like that. :)